# Wifi signal drops out when streaming online videos on 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have a stranger problem whenever I try to stream online videos my wifi signal drops and eventually it gets disconnected. This problem doesn't happen to me on windows.

On my router settings, it appears that my connection rate drops to 1Mbps when the video is trying to buffer and when I stop the video it returns to normal.

My network controller is **Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)**

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and so far what I managed to try:

- disabled the 802.11n protocol using

  ```
   sudo echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
  ```
- turned off Wireless power management
- Reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and still I have the same issue
- Tried this form [Easy Linux Tips](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/intel-wifi.html#ID2):

  ```
  echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8" |
  sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-3options.conf
  ```
- Installed the officially backported iwlwifi driver

  ```
  sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
  ```

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with "video streaming" activity? What happens if you just connect your computer to the same Wi-Fi and leave it there for some time? Most of the references you gave in the post are related to wireless driver issues, which eventually drops Wi-Fi connection even if you do not do anything. - Btw, unfortunately, I have the issues with my own laptop (>3 years old) yet Ubuntu 20.04 LTS still cannot operate its onboard wireless adapter properly after trying those solutions myself.

Comment: this only happens during video streaming only and any other thing I do online or even leaving the laptop idle doesn't affect the internet connection... I thought it might be a driver issue so I tried this stuff but still the same issue.. 
this issue doesn't happen in windows or any other device so I don't think it's a router issue .....
if there is no solution for this issue I will return to windows and use WSL instead

Comment: My personal experience with Wi-Fi on Ubuntu has not been enjoyable. I am not sure what exactly is happening in your case, but there are a few more things you could try for troubleshooting if possible: 1. Connect the same machine to the same router using Ethernet (wired), see if this still exists. 2. Use a USB Wi-Fi adapter on the same machine and see if anything improves. 3. Download a large file using `wget` or `curl`, instead of streaming video, see what happens.

Comment: Actually, I found something interesting that seems to be causing the problem, I was always using my Bluetooth headset, So, I tried turning off the Bluetooth and It worked fine, for some reason Bluetooth is interfering with wifi, the same exact moment I turned it off, the video started loading and it everything works just fine...

Comment: I tried a lot of solution but [this one](https://techvorm.com/fix-wifi-not-working-slows-ubuntu-bluetooth-turned) that only worked.... but It the permanent step doesn't work for me‍♂️

Comment: Is your Wi-Fi on 5 GHz or 2.4 GHz?

Comment: @bfrguci 2.4 GHz

Comment: Then, sure. Bluetooth is also 2.4 GHz. So another possible solution is to buy a Wi-Fi router that has 5 GHz (if your computer's Wi-Fi adapter supports it) or wait until the end of this year maybe to get one that has 5 GHz and 6 GHz.

Comment: I have the same problem without using Bluetooth at all. The problem also appears during Skype calls for instance. Anything having to do with video transfer crashes WiFi. After reconnecting the problem is usually gone. So it only used to happen once, but every time I reboot.